# Electron - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'showOpenDialog')

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, dialog

I'm trying to open the dialog on electron, but I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'showOpenDialog')
```

I've already visited several forums and communities to see if I have a solution to my problem. But none resolved perhaps because of the version.

The version of electron I currently use is `16.0.5`

This answer didn't help me much

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63756725/14271847

I won't leave all of my main.js, but the part I changed is this one, `enableRemoteModule`:

```
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      enableRemoteModule:true,
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })
```

### file test.js

And here's what I'm trying to do on electron, following what's in this [link](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog)

```
const { dialog } = require('electron')
console.log(dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections'] }))
```

I've tried it with the remote, but it doesn't work:

```
const { dialog } = require('electron')
console.log(dialog.remote.showOpenDialog({ properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections'] }))
```

Could someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Enabling [Context Isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation) and disabling nodeIntegration is best practice nowadays to truly secure your Electron application. Additionally, the use of `remote` is discouraged as we now have [Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc).

Not knowing what your `preload.js` script looks like, I have included a simple `preload.js` script below that uses a list of whitelisted channel names and implementation of [`ipcRenderer`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer) methods only. That said, having a different looking `preload.js` script should not change too much the core approach that should be used in
your `main.js` and `index.html` files to get your dialog working.

---

Using of the `invoke` method will allow us to send a message to the main process to open the dialog **and** receive a reply, all in one.

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components.
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': [
            'dialog:openMultiFileSelect' // Channel name
        ]
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

A summary on the use of the above `preload.js` script is shown below.

```js
/**
 * Render --> Main
 * ---------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.on('channel', (event, data) => { methodName(data); })
 *
 * Main --> Render
 * ---------------
 * Main:    windowName.webContents.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.receive('channel', (data) => { methodName(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Value) --> Render
 * ----------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.invoke('channel', data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', (event, data) => { return someMethod(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Promise) --> Render
 * ------------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRender.invoke('channel', data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', async (event, data) => {
 *              return await promiseName(data)
 *                  .then(() => { return result; })
 *          });
 */
```

---

In the `main.js` script, using the `handle` method, let's listen for a message on the `dialog:openMultiFileSelect` channel. Once received, open the [`dialog.showOpenDialog()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options) method and `.then` wait for a result. Once a result has been received (IE: Files selected and dialog accepted), return the result (via the `handle` method)  back to the render process.

`main.js` (main process)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronDialog = require('electron').dialog;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

const nodePath = require("path");

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

electronIpcMain.handle('dialog:openMultiFileSelect', () => {
    let options = {
        properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections']
    };

    return electronDialog.showOpenDialog(window, options)
        .then((result) => {
            // Bail early if user cancelled dialog
            if (result.canceled) { return }

            return result.filePaths;
        })
})
```

---

Finally, in the `index.html` file, we listen for a `click` event on the button and then send a message via the `dialog:openMultiFileSelect` channel to open the dialog (in the main process). Once a result is returned, `.then` display the selected file(s).

> Note how we detect a result of `undefined` and manage it accordingly. This occurs when the user cancels the dialog.

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Open File Dialog">

        <ul id="paths"></ul>
    </body>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.ipcRender.invoke('dialog:openMultiFileSelect')
                .then((paths) => {
                    if (paths === undefined) { return } // Dialog was cancelled

                    let result = '';

                    for (let path of paths) {
                        result += '<li>' + path + '</li>';
                    }

                    document.getElementById('paths').innerHTML = result;
                })
        })
    </script>
</html>
```