# how to handle upload dialog in electron JS webview

Tags: javascript, electron

In electron JS  web view , when we click on an input file element a attach dialog will be showed
I need to handle this dialog to cancel or attach file
but I checked electron document but it doesn't have any method how can I handle it?

Comment: This would have to do with regular JS. Take a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70521414/electron-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-sho/72122754#72122754) help you in the right direction? If not, add more detail to your question and I will see what I can do.